# How to control and preview particle systems texture orientation & mapping

Tags: particles, eevee-render-engine, hair

I want to dynamically control the length of leaves along the trunk of a tree using particle hair in Eevee.

I'm using a vertex group to emit hair along a cylinder(trunk) with loop cuts and I'm rendering that hair as a collection of objects(leaves).
I want to apply a gradient texture vertically to my cylinder where black is length 0 and white is length 1.

The leaves length can be adjusted by the position of the black or white handles in the Color Ramp, but each leaf is affected the same, so I assume that the mapping of my control texture is incorrect, but I can't figure out how to control or even preview it's current orientation and mapping.

[image]

Comment: Why do you have a vertex group for the length? Have you tried 'UV' for the mapping? This works for me.

Comment: @Blunder The vertex group for length is just a leftover from lots of experimentation, removing it changes nothing. I've tried every mapping method available in the dropdown, including UV, no visible difference (I've UV mapped the cylinder by projecting from view).

Comment: One difference I see is the image texture. I've created ome with the gradient fill brush and haven't tried the built-in "blend'.